# check if POST request exist in database and return custom response in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i am creating basic Coupon verification Django Rest framework APP, i just want to pass json parameter through Postman and get custom response if coupon code is valid or invalid.

Here is my models.py File:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Coupon(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code
```

Here is my Serializers.py file:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Coupon


class CouponSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Coupon
        fields = '__all__'
```

I like to write views for given serializer and get custom message as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DRF [APIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/) or [mixins](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#mixins) for this. The example for APIView:

```
class CouponValidationVie(APIView):

    queryset = Coupon.objects

    def get(self, request, code, format=None):
        try:
            coupon = Coupon.objects.get(code=code)
        except Coupon.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(
                data={"message": "custom error message"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
            )
        serializer = CouponSerializer(coupon)
        resp = {"data": serializer.data, "message": "custom success message"} 
        return Response(resp, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

If `Coupon` record found it'll serialize record data and respond it with your custom "ok" message; else custom "failure" message returned.

Comment: The owner wants to custom POST method, guy. And no need to custom a view in this case, just need to use Unique in model or custom create/validate method in Serializer, I think.

Comment: @VuPhan `POST` method doesn't make sense to simply retrieve a single record data. Anyway, if `POST` is actually needed OP can replace view method with approptiate one. `code` field already is a unique field, but I believe you're right about validation on serializer level - you make this as an answer to OP's question.

Comment: Make sense to me!

Comment: 'CouponValidationView' should either include a `queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method. getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Open POSTMAN and hit the verification url with raw request body like this `{"code":"CouponCodeHere"}`

For the verification url write the following view:

```
import json
from yourApp.models import Coupon
from django.http import HttpResponse

def check_coupon(request):
    couponDict = json.loads(request.body)
    try:
        couponCode = couponDict["code"]
        #You can apply strip i.e couponCode.strip() here to remove white spaces at the start and end.
        if Coupon.objects.filter(code=couponCode).exists():  
            return HttpResponse("valid")

        return HttpResponse("invalid")

    except KeyError:
        return HttpResponse("code does not exist in request body")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e) #For debugging purpose
        return HttpResponse("Error")
```

Comment: TypeError: check_coupon() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request' getting this error.

Comment: Please show how you are mapping this view to verification url. Add ```urls.py``` in question details.

Answer (score 0):

You can you [UniqueValidator](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/). Example code:

```
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueValidator
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Coupon

ERROR_MESSAGE_CODE_UNIQUE = 'This code already exists'


class CouponSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        validators=[
            UniqueValidator(
                queryset=Coupon.objects.all(),
                message=ERROR_MESSAGE_CODE_UNIQUE,
            )])

    class Meta:
        model = Coupon
        fields = '__all__'
```